# Filter attributes in Laravel Resource Collection

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In the new Laravel Resource classes, you are able to remove attributes based on anything you like.

If you want to return many items, you can use the function

```
Resource::collection()
```

But that does not let you add metadata in one place. Enter a Collection, great, this is many items in a nice format with the ability to add meta data. What you cannot do though, is filter the collection you have to hide attributes like you can with a resource. The only way I can see to do it is

```
foreach ($this->collection as $item) {
        if ($notAdmin) {
            $temp = array_except($item->toArray(), ['secret']);
        }
        $temp['links'] = ['self' => route('restaurant.show', [$item])];
        $data[] = $temp;
    }
```

Is there something I am missing? This seems like a massive overlooked ability for a Resource Collection

Comment: [Conditional attributes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-resources#conditional-attributes). This seems pretty much what you're looking for I think.

Comment: That is only with a resource, not a collection. What my complaint is that I would always have to loop through the collection to hide assets, I am surprised there is not a way to define hiding stuff on the collection

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based in [this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-55-api-resources-for-collections) thread, it seems that when using a [ResourceCollection](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Http/Resources/Json/ResourceCollection.html) class to customize a collection (for example `BookCollection`) Laravel look up for a [Resource](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Http/Resources/Json/Resource.html)
 class named the same but without the *Collection* sufix class (in the example, a class named just `Book`).

So you will need to have a resource class named: `Book` where you customize the attributes to be returned to the response and a collection class named: `BookCollection`, that will use `Book` -to customize the data- and will also let you customize the metadata.

#### app/Http/Resources/Book.php

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\Resource;

class Book extends Resource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'title' => $this->title,
        ];
    }
}
```

#### app/Http/Resources/BookCollection.php

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources\Users;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\ResourceCollection;

class BookCollection extends ResourceCollection
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource collection into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return $this->collection;
    }

    public function with($request)    
    {
        return [
            'meta' => [
                'key' => 'value',
            ],
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, if that is the case, they absolutely need to make this more clear in the documentation. I will try this my self then mark this as accepted.

Comment: Give it a try, if this doesn't work you can always use the @devk solution.

Comment: Yeah, seems like there are multiple ways of doing it. But it definitely could be documented better.

Comment: This seems the most "Laravel" way of doing it. I thinks @devk way is fine, but this seems more framework friendly

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's how you do it:

1. Create a `Resource` for a single resource, where [you can](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-resources#conditional-attributes) easily have conditional attributes
2. Create a `RCollection` for the collection, where you can add [meta data](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-resources#adding-meta-data).
3. Pass the `Resource::collection(Model::all)` into the `new RCollection()`.

Something like this (from my testing):

```
Route::get('users/all', function() {
    return new \App\Http\Resources\Users(
        \App\Http\Resources\UserResource::collection(\App\User::get())
    );
});
```

Works like a charm!